# in windows 10, all files in explorer ftp window have associated with chrome, how can I change this?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat

I tried out an app on my android phone called cx explorer mentioned here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167789/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-phone-filesystem-from-computer-wireless  my aim was to view files from my android "phone", on my computer, wirelessly.

Windows 10 does have a native "Your phone" program, with a corresponding android app, currently called "link to windows", it shows images but(as of writing), not videos, so I looked to the cx explorer app.

The cf explorer app has a feature whereby it sets up an ftp server on the phone and so from the computer I can ftp://privateip:someportnumber , enter a user/pass,  and view folders on my "phone"

[image]

As you see the files look like they are associated with a native windows photo viewer program, but if i double click it , it goes to chrome.

When I first double clicked a jpg, it didn't open in anything. It prompted me asking me how i'd like to open it, and it offered web browsers chrome and edge, and  it offered going to "the microsoft store", to find an app to open it. And it didn't offer any browse option for me to choose a program. Certainly when it comes to videos there is a program I want to try.

So given the limited options, I just chose a web browser like chrome.

But

a) chrome won't open it, chrome just opens a new tab

b)  since choosing for the jpg to be opened in chrome, all other files in that ftp window seem to be afflicted. so e.g. if i double click an mp4, then chrome opens.

If I copy paste the file to a normal folder, then when right clicking the file I get a regular context menu, with an "open with" option, and when double clicking the file it opens photos or videos in a standard windows 10 program for viewing photos or videos.

Notice that if you look at the icon to the left of the filenames listed in the explorer window for the ftp url, you see it's not a chrome icon, it looks like the icon for a standard windows 10 photo viewer program.  And outside of an explorer window with ftp url, it does open them normally.

**added**

one suggestion in comment was to try WinSCP.

WinSCP does indeed support FTP, and SFTP too, though here we are just talking FTP. Winscp (perhaps using a temporary directory to store a copy of the file), opens the jpg in winscp editor which is like notepad, this is the case on the win10 laptop from my question, and on a win7 laptop that i've i use a lot. So winscp is a red herring, in that it has its own issue if trying to do that. (great program though).

So back to the explorer window.

When trying a win7 laptop i use a lot, / runs well, and I open an explorer window and go to the IP:port, iand double click the jpg, it opens it in a web browser! `file:///C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary%20Internet%20Files/Content.IE5/RFNKM9WY/IMG_20210225_121502209[2].jpg` though the default for opening a jpg is irfanview so if it were in a regular folder / folder on the hard drive of the laptop, it'd open in irfanview.

On that laptop if I try to open an mp4 video it says "file system error".  [image]

On the win10 laptop whether I double click a jpg or an mp4, it opens chrome, and doesn't even attempt to open any file. (though in theory it could potentially open a jpg).  I tried from another directory of the device(before was the directory of the SD card this time the directory of thte internal memory, though main relevance is a different directory), browsing to it via explorer and the FTP URL, and it prompted me asking me what program i wish to open it in, offering chrome or edge, not offering much.  I don't recall if it offered much more, or an option for me to browse. It had a box for "always" that I didn't tick. So I expected to maybe get that option up again, though i didn't. It just keeps trying to open it in chrome.

Comment: It may help to narrow down if this is a File Explorer issue or a Windows issue by using a third party FTP viewer to see if the same is replicated _(I think WinSCP can do FTP)_

Comment: @JW0914 i've added to my question

Comment: That's just odd all around and seems more like a bug to me, as I can't imagine why that would be expected behavior; however the other side to that is that's a really long time for a bug like that to be around and no one notice considering how widely used FTP is _(I only ever use SCP, unless using WinSCP with OpenSSH, but never to access media files)_. It may be worth your time to file a bug report with Microsoft. Something that may work, albeit it's inefficient, would be to use a program that supports command line to open the media files _(VLC does, unsure about native Windows programs)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ I'm more familiar with SCP than FTP, but a few questions that occurred to me are _(not posed to you, simply in general)_: is this an issue with FTP in general or just cx explorer's implementation of it? Does this occur with other protocols like SSH or SCP _(albeit running an SSH server may not be available if your android device isn't rooted)_? If this doesn't occur with SSH or SCP, why does it with FTP? I know `adb` supports wireless, but unless something's changed, it's not secure to use.

Comment: @JW0914 it's not an FTP or SCP or SFTP issue. It's an issue with Windows's FTP browsing, and the clients. The idea with FTP/SCP/SFTP, is   file transfer, not about letting a user double click an icon and opening the relevant program.  So FTP clients are lazy about adding that feature.  Really even when people plug a phone into a computer with  a usb cable they tend to copy things across and then open them, rather than double click them. And they might double click an image though less likely a video 'cos it'd have to copy over each time...

Comment: @JW0914 (cntd)  So the software would have to choose whether to  copy it to some temporary file, which takes space, or copy it fresh every time. And maybe they just can't be bothered. But on a mapped network drive I think microsoft do bother.   Looks like it could be possible to map a network drive for FTP though https://www.digitalcitizen.life/map-network-drive-ftp-websites-windows-10/  so that could solve it..  (I figured I could map an SFTP drive.. with some third party thing, wasn't sure about FTP, but I see there's a way, so that's what I will try next)